# Split Background - stop moving as panels expand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

So I have a split background - the top is blue, and the bottom is white. I am using this style to  get the split background:

```js
//accordion - changes colour on open / close

var selectIds = $('#panel1,#panel2,#panel3');
$(function($) {
  selectIds.on('show.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).prev().find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
  });
  $(".panel-heading").find("a[data-toggle=collapse]").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
      $(this).closest('.panel-group').find('.panel-default').removeClass('open');
      $(this).closest('.panel-default').addClass('open');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.panel-default').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.gradient {
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#18A9E5, #18A9E5 49.9%, #fff 50.1%, #fff 100%);
}
.split {
  width: 100%;
  /*height:50px;*/
  max-height: 25%;
  padding: 2% 5% 5% 5%;
}
.solid-white {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 0!important;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .26);
  h2 {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
}
.page-section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  &.page-section-md {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
.panel-body-help {
  background-color: #616161;
  color: white;
}
.panel-default.open {
  background-color: #616161;
  transition: all 0s;
}
.custom-panel {
  .panel-default.open {
    > .panel-heading {
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: bolder;
      background: transparent;
    }
  }
}
.custom-panel {
  .panel-default {
    > .panel-heading {
      background: #fff;
    }
  }
}
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.panel-body {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section class="page-section page-section-md split gradient">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h4 class="heading-responsive text-white">
               Welcome
            </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container wrap-md">
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 solid-white-help">
      <h2 class="heading-responsive thin">Welcome</h2>
      <br />
      <div class="panel-group custom-panel" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle collapsed text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Get started
                            </a>
                        </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
              CONTENT
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Utilities</a>
                        </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
              CONTENT
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Organization</a>
                        </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
              CONTENT
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel4"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Integrations</a>
                        </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="panel4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
              CONTENT
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel5"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Essentials</a>
                        </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="panel5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
              CONTENT
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel6"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Sales</a>
                        </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="panel6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
              CONTENT
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel7"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Support</a>
                        </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="panel7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
              CONTENT
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel8"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Projects</a>
                        </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="panel8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
              CONTENT
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
</section>
```

Since I have the bootstrap panels inside the background, when i expand a panel, the background also moves. (as in the blue extends lower as i open panels). 
How can i make the colors fixed no matter what size my background is?

https://support.google.com/mail#topic=3394144 < this is a good reference for what i am trying to achieve with the background not moving when panels are expanded.

This is likely a really easy fix and i am just missing it -  thanks for your help! TIA.

Comment: Instead of adding the gradient directly to the `section` element, try adding a new child element or use a pseudo-element, positioned absolutely with a set height. That way the element with the gradient does not grow taller as you add more content to the `section` element.

Comment: Can you provide full code?

Comment: I am using boot straps panel css - i included above the .solid-white style i was missing @TOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the blue top is determined by your background gradient on the'.gradient' class (currently top 49.9% is blue and bottom 50.1% is white). You can give your .split class a height of 100vh and overflow: scroll.

```
.split {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 2% 5% 5% 5%;
}
```

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wietsedevries/bk4ogp38/3/

Comment: works to keep the background still, but cuts my content off at the very top. I cant even see my full accordion now.

Is that something i did?

Comment: It shouldn't cut anything off, unless you have 'overflow:hidden;' set on .split?

Comment: I have another class with overflow hidden. I removed it, and it still doesn't display quite right. 
doesnt want to show the complete page.

Comment: You would have to give me more code to look at. Using the code you've posted, this works.

Comment: Try will the added code above - not sure if they help at all... but i also included the page-section which have the overflow hidden.

Comment: overflow: hidden; is on the same element as .split ...  I'm going to edit my answer.